# IF statements not outputting proper value

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been trying to automate a process in excel with vba and I seem to be having trouble. I haven't done a lot with vba before and I appreciate any help. I have asked a couple questions before and looked up info on google and here, but my program still isn't running properly.

If I run this code just once then it works perfectly fine, but I want to run it 30 times with results continually updating and putting the new answer into a different cell then it doesn't work. Basically returns the correct answer for the first run but every time after that it generates the wrong response.

So below is my code, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
For i = 19 To 19

    Range("AA3:AA7").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    If Cells(i, 26) > 499999 Then
        Cells(3, 27) = 499999
    ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 499999 Then
        Cells(3, 27) = Cells(i, 26)
    End If

    If Cells(3, 27) < 499999 Then
         Cells(5, 27) = 0
    ElseIf Cells(i, 26) > 999999 Then
        Cells(4, 27) = 500000
    ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 999999 Then
        Cells(4, 27) = Cells(i, 26) - 499999
    End If

    If Cells(4, 27) = 0 Then
         Cells(5, 27) = 0
    ElseIf Cells(i, 26) > 1999999 Then
        Cells(5, 27) = 1000000
    ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 1999999 Then
        Cells(5, 27) = Cells(i, 26) - 999999
    End If

    If Cells(5, 27) = 0 Then
         Cells(6, 27) = 0
    ElseIf Cells(i, 26) > 4999999 Then
         Cells(6, 27) = 3000000
    ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 4999999 Then
        Cells(6, 27) = Cells(i, 26) - 1999999
    End If

    If Cells(6, 27) = 0 Then
         Cells(7, 27) = 0
    ElseIf Cells(6, 27) = 3000000 Then
         Cells(7, 27) = Cells(3, i) - 4999999
    End If

    Cells(i, 30).Value = (Cells(3, 28) + Cells(4, 28) + Cells(5, 28) + Cells(6, 28) + Cells(7, 28)) / Cells(i, 26)

 Next i
```

Comment: What cell and value is an example of a correct answer?

Comment: at the top of the code it is 19 to 49 not 19 to 19, sorry

Comment: 1) Does this **need** to be VBA? Can you just work it out with spreadsheet formulas? 2) It's a lot of gnarly logic and without a sample data very hard to determine where it's going awry. Have you stepped through the code, line-by-line (debugging), to see what is happening on the 2nd (and beyond) iteration that is causing to not perform as you expect?

Comment: Maybe I'll just make a manual spreadsheet, that probably would have been easier for me, I just thought this way would have been quicker, thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got anything in place for when the value is exactly the figure eg <499999 and >499999 doesn't account for =499999.

You also don't need to state next i - just a next will do.

I'm not sure why you're updating a cell then adding them together, you'd be better off assigning the cell values to variables as with the below. If you'd like to see where it is going wrong I may be an idea to add msgbox calls to show the values as it iterates:

> Dim I as integer

Dim value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 as integer

For i = 19 To 49

```
If Cells(i, 26) > 499999 Then
    Value1=499999
Else 
     Value1=Cells(i, 26)
End If
```

' and so on...

```
Cells(i, 30).Value = value1+value2 etc...
```

Next